# Using Async/Await In React for API Response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, components, rendering

So basically the API is going to send back a response that is `true/false` based on user input and I'm trying to set the variable `res` to be that response so I can use that to render the next component.  However, I need to wait until the response has actually come back, otherwise the value is just going to be false because it is running the code below the `axios` post before it actually goes through.  So I decided to use `async/await` but for some reason it is reloading the original form ApplyForm now? When I take out async and await it doesn't do that so I am very confused.  Can someone help figure out the issue or suggest an alternative way of doing this? Any help is appreciated thanks.

ApplyForm.js

```js
    import React from "react";
    import Component from "react";
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm.js'

    class ApplyForm extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {providerID: ''}
      }

      handleSubmit = (e) => {
      ReactDOM.render(<PaymentForm data = {this.state.providerID} />, document.getElementById('root'));
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
       this.setState({
         providerID: e.target.value,
       });
     }

     shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
     }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <h1> Apply for a payment plan </h1>
        <p>Four Letter Provider ID:</p>
        <input
          type='text'
          name = "providerID"
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <br></br>
        <small> If you do not have a provider ID, you can skip this part. </small>
        <p>Payment Plan Amount:</p>
        <input
          type='number'
          required
          onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
        />
         <p>Your Procedure:</p>
         <input
           type='text'
           name = "Procedure"
           required
           onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
        </form>
      );
    }
      }

    export default ApplyForm;
```

PaymentForm.js

```js
    import React from "react";
    import Component from "react";
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import Link from './Link.js';
    import axios from 'axios'
    let res = false;

    class PaymentForm extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {provID: this.props.data};
     }

      async handleSubmit(event) {
      const data = new FormData(event.target);
      const res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'test-url',
        data: {
            httpMethod: "POST",
            body: {
                UID: "123456",
                Last_Name: data.get('Last_Name'),
                personal_data: {
                    Treatment_Plan: data.get('Plan'),
                    First_Name: data.get('First_Name'),
                    Last_Name: data.get('Last_Name'),
                    Address: data.get('Address'),
                    Unit: data.get('Unit'),
                    City: data.get('City'),
                    State: data.get('State'),
                    Zip: data.get('Zip'),
                    Email: data.get('Email'),
                    Employment_status: data.get('Employment_status'),
                    EST_Credit: data.get('EST_Credit'),
                    Phone: data.get('Phone'),
                    DOB: data.get('DOB'),
                    Income: data.get('Income'),
                    Rent: data.get('Rent'),
                    SSN: data.get('SSN'),
                    Co_App: data.get('Test'),
                },
                provider_data: {
                    Provider_ID: this.state.provID,
                    Procedure_Amount: data.get('Request_Amount'),
                    Procedure_Des: data.get('Loan_Purpose')
                },
            }
        }
      }).then((response) => {
          res = response['data']['is_passed'];
          console.log(res);
      });

      if (res) {
        ReactDOM.render(<Link />, document.getElementById('root'));
      }

    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <h1> See Your Loan Options </h1>
        <p>Request $1000 to $100000</p>
        <input
            type='Number'
            name = "Request_Amount"
            onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
        />
        <br></br>

        <p>Loan Purpose:</p>
        <input
            type='text'
            name = "Loan_Purpose"
            required
            onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
        />

         <p>Do you already have a treatment plan for your procedure?</p>
         <input type="radio" id="Yes" value = "Yes" name = "Plan" onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
         <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
         <input type="radio" id="No" value = "No" name = "Plan" onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
         <label for="Yes">No</label>
        <br></br>

        <p>What is the name of your provider?</p>
            <input type='text' name = "Provider" required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>First Name</p>
            <input type='text' name = "First_Name" required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>Last Name</p>
            <input type='text' name = "Last_Name" required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>Street Address</p>
            <input type='text' name = "Address" required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>Unit Number</p>
            <input type='text' name = "Unit_Number" onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>City</p>
            <input type='text' name = "City"  required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>State</p>
            <select name = "State" >
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>State</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>Zip Code</p>
            <input type='text' name = "Zip" required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>Email Address</p>
            <input type='email' name = "Email" required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

            <p>Confirm Email Address</p>
            <input type='email' required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <select name = "Employment_status" >
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Employment Status</option>
            <option value="E">Employed</option>
            <option value="U">Unemployed</option>
            <option value="S">Self Employed</option>
            <option value="M">Military</option>
            <option value="R">Retired Benefits</option>
            <option value="O">Other</option>
          </select>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>

          <select name = "EST_Credit" >
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Estimated Credit Range</option>
            <option value="E"> > 720</option>
            <option value="U">680 - 720</option>
            <option value="S">640 - 679</option>
            <option value="M">550 - 639</option>
            <option value="R"> &#60; 550 </option>
          </select>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>

         <p>Mobile</p>
            <input type='text' name = "Phone" required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>Date of Birth (yyyy/dd/mm)</p>
            <input type='text' name = "DOB" required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>Annual Individual Income</p>
            <input type='text' name = "Income" required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

            <select name = "Rent" >
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Housing Status</option>
            <option value="E">Rent</option>
            <option value="U">Mortgage</option>
            <option value="S">Fully-Owned</option>
            <option value="M">Partially-Owned</option>
            <option value="R">Other</option>
          </select>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>

          <p>Social Security Number</p>
            <input type = "password" name = "SSN"  required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

          <p>Confirm Social Security Number</p>
            <input type = "password" required onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

         <p>Do you want to add a co-applicant?</p>
         <input type="radio" id="Yes" value = "Yes" name = "Test" onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
          <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
          <input type="radio" id="No" value = "No" name = "Test" onChange={this.myChangeHandler}/>
          <label for="Yes">No</label>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>

        <input type="checkbox" required id="Agree"/>
        <label for = "Agree"> Our Terms of Use, Privacy Policy, Credit Report Authorization and Telephone and Email Consents.</label>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>

        <button>See My Rates</button>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }

export default PaymentForm;
```

Comment: you need to `e.preventDefault()` on the form submit handler to prevent the default behavior of your form (submitting the page which reloads it)

Comment: Can you explain this further? In which submit handler? Thanks

Comment: You have a form. `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`. When a form submits, its default behavior is to post the page to the server which also refreshes the page because usually the server would return a new page to render. When doing a single page application, you dont want the form to actually submit the page, so you need to prevent this behavior. the function `handleSubmit` accepts the submit event you've aliased as `e`. So the very fist line of the `handleSubmit` function you need to add `e.preventDefault()`. I suggest you read up on [form submission](https://javascript.info/forms-submit)

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using promises then you don't need to use `async-await` again. `async-await` is an alternative syntax for promises.

the problem with your code is you need to do redirect after the promise is resolved.

you just need to move the redirect part inside `.then` method like so.

```
    const res = axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'test-url',
    data: {
        httpMethod: "POST",
        body: {
            UID: "123456",
            Last_Name: data.get('Last_Name'),
            personal_data: {
                Treatment_Plan: data.get('Plan'),
                First_Name: data.get('First_Name'),
                Last_Name: data.get('Last_Name'),
                Address: data.get('Address'),
                Unit: data.get('Unit'),
                City: data.get('City'),
                State: data.get('State'),
                Zip: data.get('Zip'),
                Email: data.get('Email'),
                Employment_status: data.get('Employment_status'),
                EST_Credit: data.get('EST_Credit'),
                Phone: data.get('Phone'),
                DOB: data.get('DOB'),
                Income: data.get('Income'),
                Rent: data.get('Rent'),
                SSN: data.get('SSN'),
                Co_App: data.get('Test'),
            },
            provider_data: {
                Provider_ID: this.state.provID,
                Procedure_Amount: data.get('Request_Amount'),
                Procedure_Des: data.get('Loan_Purpose')
            },
        }
    }
  }).then((response) => {
      res = response['data']['is_passed'];
      console.log(res);
      if (res) {
        ReactDOM.render(<Link />, document.getElementById('root'));
     }
  });
```

Comment: I tried this and it reloads the original component for some reason. Is it the same reason as the comment on my question?

Comment: Did you remove async await and try